# How can I use a variable created inside server.js in my ejs script tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm building my first NodeJS project which has a lot of file managment. I thought that to make my life easier it would be beneficial to get a passed variable that was created in my server.js inside the script tag that exists inside one of my ejs files. This is the sample of the code I want to work with:

```
// My server.js file - I want to use the variable "files" inside my ejs script tag
app.get('/feed', (req, res) => {
    let files = fs.readdirSync("./uploads");
    res.status(200).render('feed', {files});
});
```

```
// My ejs file - this is what I found on Google and tried, yet it did not work
    <% let f = files %>
  </body>
  <script>
    let getFiles = <%= f %>;
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Any help would be helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

So in order to use a variable created serverside on the frontend you need to pass it in as a prop.

To pass in props to views in express, we pass in an object as the second parameter in the res.render method:

We can't just pass in a variable or something else as a prop. We need to reassign them first.

```
res.render(view, {
  prop1: value,
  prop2: newValue,
});
```

Here, we reassigned value and newValue to prop1 and prop2 respectively.

So, the solution to your question,

`res.status(200).render('feed', {f: files})`

Here, we simply took the files variable and passed it in as a prop by ressigning it to the name f. We can use this in our view by:

`<% files %>`

Comment: Hello, please edit your answer explaining why this fixes the authors issues.